# Хочу учиться Android разработке

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Собираюсь делать это через Intellij IDEA (т.к. использую эту среду разработки при изучении Java и как-то не хочется уходить с нее на Android Studio). Возник вопрос: есть ли возможность использовать как эмулятор при разработке обычный Blue Stacks? Или обязательно качать что-то другое(если да, то что именно)?

Comment: Возможность, конечно, есть, но будет большое количество проблем, не возникающих на Android Studio. Если выбор не обусловлен малым количеством памяти на диске - советую все же использовать Android Studio,ее интерфейс в любом случае очень близок к обычной IDEA, так что, в плане использования, дискомфорта не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio - это и есть Intellij IDEA (только немного запоздалая и урезанная, в том плане, что писать можно только под Android (почти)).

В Intellij IDEA так же можно разрабатывать проекты под Android, там же можно и android sdk/ndk прикрутить и всё т.п.

Но всё же рекомендую попробовать Android Studio - она действительно удобна!